# Android coordinate system:drawing goes out of screen on smaller screen devices

Tags: android, view, drawing, android-canvas, coordinate-systems

I am creating an android app in which user can draw something on my custom view. I am saving the points from motion event and trying to redraw the path on another android device. It works fine.

But if the screen size of the second device is smaller than the first one some part of the drawing goes off the screen.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: see [Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: You have to develop a logic whith current device-screen size. for that you can do--->      WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Answer (score 0):

you can get the window resolution of first device and compare with second device.
As the width and height of the screen changes u change the size of your draw